# R: Sum variables based on some condition

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, count, data-manipulation

Given a table, I am trying to learn how to use R for summing variables based on when a certain condition is met (based on other variables in the same table).

Using the dplyr library, (I created some data) and then summed the data by groups :

```
#load library
library(dplyr)

#create data
data <- data.frame(
    
    "col_a" = c("aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa"),
    "col_b" = c("123", "124", "125", "126", "127", "128", "129", "130"),
"col_c" = c("2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"),
"col_d" = c("red", "red", "red", "blue", "blue", "green", "green", "green"),
"day_a" = c("2001-01-01", "2000-01-05", "2000-01-01", "2010-12-20", "2010-12-20", "2020-05-05", "2020-05-05", "2020-05-28"),
"day_b" = c("2001-01-10", "2000-01-10", "2000-01-01", "2010-12-25", "2010-12-22", "2020-05-15", "2020-05-20", "2020-05-30")

)

#format variable types

data$col_a = as.factor(data$col_a)
data$col_b = as.factor(data$col_b)
data$col_c = as.factor(data$col_c)

#format date variables
data$day_a = as.factor(data$day_a)
data$day_b = as.factor(data$day_b)

data$day_1 = as.Date(as.character(data$day_a))
data$day_2 = as.Date(as.character(data$day_b))

#create new variable based on difference between date variables
data$diff = data$day_2 - data$day_1
data$diff = as.numeric(data$diff)

#create file that sums days based on groups of "col_a, col_c, col_d"
file = data%>%
    group_by(col_a, col_c, col_d) %>% 
    dplyr::summarize(Total = sum(diff, na.rm=TRUE), Count = n()) 

file = as.data.frame(file)
```

Now, for groups of "col_a, col_c, col_d", I want to sum the "diff" variable based on another condition.

For example, for the group "aaa, 2015, green", I want to only sum the "unique days" - i.e. the days that overlap. (2020-05-05, 2020-05-15), ( 2020-05-05, 2020-05-20), (2020-05-28 ,2020-05-30)

For this group, I want the value of the "total" variable = 15 + 2 = 17 ... instead of "27".

This is because the dates(2020-05-05, 2020-05-15) is completely within the dates ( 2020-05-05, 2020-05-20). I only want to sum the "unique" date periods.

I am trying to get something in the end that looks like this:

```
final_result <- data.frame ( col_a = c("aaa", "aaa", "aaa"),
                             col_c = c("2015", "2015", "2015"), 
                             col_d = c("blue", "green", "red"),
                             total = c("5","17","9"),
count = c("2", "3", "3")
                                 
    )
```

Can anyone please show me how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach with `purrr::map2`:

First, convert the `Date` columns to integer representations. Then use `map2` to create vectors of the integer sequences between the two dates. It seems you don't want to count the last day, so I subtracted 1 from `day 2`.

Now we have a new column `dates` which holds a vector of dates as integers.

```
library(purrr)
data %>% 
  transmute(dates = map2(as.integer(day_1),as.integer(day_2)-1,seq))
1                                           11323, 11324, 11325, 11326, 11327, 11328, 11329, 11330, 11331
2                                                                       10961, 10962, 10963, 10964, 10965
3                                                                                            10957, 10956
4                                                                       14963, 14964, 14965, 14966, 14967
5                                                                                            14963, 14964
6                                    18387, 18388, 18389, 18390, 18391, 18392, 18393, 18394, 18395, 18396
7 18387, 18388, 18389, 18390, 18391, 18392, 18393, 18394, 18395, 18396, 18397, 18398, 18399, 18400, 18401
8                                                                                            18410, 18411
```

Then we can group as you did previously, and summarize by unlisting the dates for a specific group and using `unique` to remove duplicates. Then just count up the number of dates.

```
data %>% 
  mutate(dates = map2(as.integer(day_1),as.integer(day_2)-1,seq)) %>%
  group_by(col_a, col_c, col_d) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(Total = length(unique(unlist(dates))), Count = n())
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   col_a, col_c [1]
  col_a col_c col_d Total Count
  <fct> <fct> <chr> <int> <int>
1 aaa   2015  blue      5     2
2 aaa   2015  green    17     3
3 aaa   2015  red      16     3
```